# How to select only the last <p> in a <div> with No class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have div1 in this I have more `<div>`s and `<p>`s and I only want to select the `<p>` in this `<div>` and not in the other `div`s

I tried the CSS `:last-child` selector, but it selected also the last `<p>`s in the other div.

How can I do that?

This is a sample of my code:

```
<div id="div1">

    <div class="div2"><p>text</p></div>

    <div class="div3"><p>text</p></div>

    <div class="div4"><p>text</p></div>

    <p>select only me</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried in CSS?

Comment: if you want to select only the `<p>` inside `#div1`, you can use `#div1 p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the immediate children (`>`) selector along with the `:last-child` pseudo-class. This selects only `p` elements that are "first-level" (not nested) children of `#div1` and then selects only the last of those elements. See below:

```css
#div1 > p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<div class="div2"><p>text</p></div>
<div class="div3"><p>text</p></div>
<div class="div4"><p>text</p></div>
<p>select only me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
#div1 p {

}
```

Which wil select all the paragraph tags that are direct children of the div1

Comment: I tried that but it selects all p's in this id and also the other p's

Comment: `#div1 p:last-child`

Comment: #div1 > p, try that

Comment: You got it! Thank you so much! i used #div1 > p

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a general "any div's last p child" situation instead of specifying with a class.

Make a unique class for the outer, containing div to then use last-child styling on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#div1 p:last-child {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the last div, and then any p inside of that div:

```
div:last-of-type p {background:green;}
```

If you want to select the last p in any div:

```
div p:last-of-type {background:red;}
```

If you want to select the last p in last div:

```
 div:last-of-type p:last-of-type {background:blue;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just give your p a class or id like `<p class="blablabla">blablabla</p>` or `<p id="blablabla">blablabla</p>` and in CSS you do:

```
.blablabla{
  #things you want to do in CSS with class
}
```

or

```
#blablabla{
 #things you want to do in CSS with id
}
```

Comment: I can't add a class to it it's an external file